# Removing html hyperlinks anchor from text with regex (in python, pyqt4)

Tags: python, html, regex

In my QTextBrowser I detect links like "www.test.com" with

```
re.compile(   r"(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|])"   )
```

When further actions on the QTextBrowser occur, the text is received again with `text.toHtml()` and then parsed again. This leads to cascaded hyperlinks.

So I want, before parsing again, the hyperlinks HTML to be removed. For example, the text looks like

```
<a href="www.test.com">www.test.com</a>
```

after first parsing and should look like

```
www.test.com
```

before the second parsing, to prevent cascading.

How do I remove

```
<a href="SOMETHING"> and </a>
```

with a regex?

Other html-tags like bold or italic should not be removed.#

EDIT

I've heard about not parsing HTML with regex, but I think here it should be possible and I don't want further dependencies in my program.

Comment: You can use `re.sub` to remove those `<a>` tags. You just need to get the expression. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes I've used re.sub to exchange the hyperlinks. But I don't know how to get the "something" in a regex. 

The 2nd way could be, to put a further term into the the first, long regex that it ignores expressions that already have a "a href" in it, but it does not work. I tried this with (?<!a href=) but I did not see any changes.

Comment: Do you have to remove them? Why not just use a regex to capture what is in between?

Comment: My current implementation works like this:

If a 'www.test.com' is detected, it makes a '<a href=www.test.com>www.test.com</a> out of it. Then at the 2nd parsing it gets cascaded, making '<a href=<a href=www.test.com>www.test.com</a>www.test.com</a> or similar. Somehow I have to workaround this, either by first removing the 'a hrefs' or by excluding it from the first regex. The cascading occurs because the big regex searches for terms that start with www. or http:

Comment: Wait... Doesn't that mean that the second (or first) parsing is not behaving as intended? Wouldn't it be better to cure the code at its source rather than using another parser to undo whatever mistake happened!?

Comment: Yes it would be better, but I don't know how to do that. I copied the regex from a blog that dealed with detecting urls...

Comment: Maybe remove the line that passes the link to `text.toHtml()`? I don't know what you have in your code, but for maintainability, it'd be better to just prevent the double parsing. Otherwise, I guess you can just replace `</?a[^>]+>` by nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider using [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this task.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for m in soup.find_all('a'):
...     m.replaceWithChildren()
>>> print soup
```

Comment: Ok seems like using RegEx to parse Html was not the best idea on the planet. Going to take a deeper look at this. Thx